# Traefik Kubernetes (k3s): Expose non-Kubernetes service with https

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have two clusters relevant for this question.

- k3s-0 [10.12.9.113]
- k3s-2 [10.12.9.115]

Both clusters have traefik 2.4.8 running.

My interal domain `k3s.lan` points to `k3s-0`. (My DNS server is pihole)

In `k3s-0`, I have the following working perfectly.

```yaml
---      
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k2-service
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: http
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k2-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 10.12.9.115
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: http
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: nginx2
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`k2.k3s.lan`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: k2-service
          port: 80
```

when I type `http://k2.k3s.lan`, I see my nginx landing page.

Now I want to access the same landing page using `https` instead of `http`. I tried the following, but it does not work.

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k2-service-sec
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 80
    name: https
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k2-service-sec
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 10.12.9.115
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: https
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: nginx2-sec
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`k2sec.k3s.lan`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: k2-service-sec
          port: 443
```

when I type `https://k2sec.k3s.lan`, I get an `Internal Server Error`.

For reference, here are the settings of the ingressroute/service in k3s-2.
The only thing I changed here was to host `k2sec.k3s.lan` in the route.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: nginx
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`k2.k3s.lan`,`k2sec.k3s.lan`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: nginx
          port: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my own problem, thanks to [this](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/4589)

At least it is working right now. As a true beginner, all this feels like magic.

Here is the updated manifest in k3s-0.

Main changes:

- Added a `middleware` to redirect from `http` to `https`
- Referenced the `middleware` to the `web` `IngressRoute`
- Added a `ServersTransport` to set the `insecureSkipVerify` flag to `true`
- Referenced the `ServersTransport` in the `websecure` `IngressRoute`
- Added `scheme` to `https` to the `websecure` `IngressRoute`. I have not tried it without it. It may not be necessary

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: redirectscheme
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    scheme: https
    permanent: true   
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k2-service
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: http
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k2-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 10.12.9.115
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: http
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: k2-service
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`k2.k3s.lan`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: k2-service
          port: 80
      middlewares:
        - name: redirectscheme      
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k2-service-sec
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    name: https
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k2-service-sec
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 10.12.9.115
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      name: https
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: ServersTransport
metadata:
  name: traefik-servers-transport
spec:
  serverName: "test"
  insecureSkipVerify: true
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: k2-service-sec
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`k2.k3s.lan`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: k2-service-sec
          port: 443                
          scheme: https
          serversTransport: traefik-servers-transport
```

I also changed the IngressRoute in k3s-2

- Added a `middleware` to redirect from `http` to `https`
- Referenced the `middleware` to the `web` `IngressRoute`
- Create a new `websecure` `IngressRoute`

Here it is:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
 name: redirectscheme
spec:
 redirectScheme:
   scheme: https
   permanent: true  
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
   run: nginx
 name: nginx
spec:
 ports:
 - port: 80
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 80
 selector:
   run: nginx
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
 name: nginx
spec:
 entryPoints:
   - web
 routes:
   - match: Host(`k2.k3s.lan`)
     kind: Rule
     services:
       - name: nginx
         port: 80
     middlewares:
       - name: redirectscheme
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
 name: nginx-sec
spec:
 entryPoints:
   - websecure
 routes:
   - match: Host(`k2.k3s.lan`)
     kind: Rule
     services:
       - name: nginx
         port: 80
```