# How do i use traefik to expose a web server outside of kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, k3s, traefik-ingress

i'm using a k3s cluster with traefik and i want to expose a nginx web server that is outside of the cluster in a VM.

I want to know if it is even possible to do that and if it is, how do i do it.

I've tried creating a Service and an Ingress but unfortunately it didn't work

I've tried using a Service with the ExternalName type

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: website-a-service
  namespace: test
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  externalName: 10.0.0.1
```

And an IngressRoute.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: website-a-service-ingress-route
  namespace: test
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`website-a-service.local`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: website-a-service
      kind: Service
      port: 80
```

After reading the kubernetes documentation i've learned that i can't use ExternalName, I don't know any way of making this work.

Comment: Could you please share the manifests you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working.

I've created an Entrypoint that matches the ip of my external machine and an IngressRoute to route everything to the address.

I've used a similar approach to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71210782/21420364).

Sorry for any inconvenience.